# Problems getting Background Page

Tags: google-chrome, background, google-chrome-extension

I am having problems with my google extension, I have followed what I believe is proper for sending information to a background page, but when I try to run my extension I am hit with "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'closer'" Does anyone know what is happening and why?

popup.html

```
var i = 0;

function start(){

        var bg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
        bg.closer(i); //chrome.extension.sendRequest({});
}

function add(){

        i++;
        document.getElementById('box').value=i;
}
function sub(){

        i--;
        document.getElementById('box').value=i;
}
```

background.html

```
var ctr = 0;

function closer(int i){

        var t=setTimeout("close()",i*500);
}

function close(){

        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
            chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id, function() { });
        });
}
```

manifest.json

```
{

    "name": "Hello World!",
    "version": "1.0",

    "description": "My first Chrome extension.",

    "permissions": ["tabs", "background"],

    "background_page": "background.html",

    "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "popup": "popup.html"   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot just send message to that bg variable.

There is a special approach to send messages to bg, please read up on sendRequest() etc.

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-sendRequest

Comment: Then what is getBackgroundPage(); meant to be used for?

Comment: You can still read the DOM on that page in case you want to get data from that page. Also, you could just close the tab out of popup.hmtl.

Comment: I could close the tab in the popup, but as far as I can tell, if I press start and the popup disappears then the counter number to delay the close would disappear immediately which isn't what I'm trying to do.